# Silverlight DataGridColumn sorting based on content (and not on underlying property)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, sorting

I have a `DataGrid`, where I am displaying some `Job` data. One of the field is calculated based on 2 columns.

There is a calculated field `StaffName` that comes from different properties (which are hidden in data grid).

I want to sort `StaffName` based on the content displayed on grid, and not based on underlying property on which `Converter` is applied. there are actually multiple underlying properties, and handling sorting of these is complex.
The data structure comes from some other assembly which is not aware of any converters/lookups which transform different property into `StaffName`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Binding={Job} SortMemberPath="StaffName"/>

Comment: There is no underlying field as StaffName, this is calculated field and this calculation is in multibinding converters.

Comment: Can you create a StaffName wrapper in a partial class to your current DataContext object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the sort event and do the Sort the itemcollection based on your need and Assign the newly sorted collection to the ItemSource . 
Following Link shows how to sort.
[Check the sample](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/sorting-data-in-the-silverlight-datagrid/)

In the example it is normal sorting, at Places LINQ queries used you need to write your own LINQ query involving the fields you want to use in the orderby clause

Comment: It is using click event. I want to rely on MVVM pattern, and not on code behind.

Comment: Hi Tilak, I believe in,MVVM also we can achieve this, following example may be of some help . http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97609/Using-the-Silverlight-DataGrid-with-View-Model-MVV

Comment: It is a very good article, I will thoroughly go through it. Sorting is there by default in silverlight. But custom sorting is hell. I want to check if there are better approaches to achieve the same.